# Show that for any $q$ in the interval $(1,2)$ exists $n$ to let the inequality of $m$ does not have positive integer solution?

Tags: inequality

Show that $\forall q \in (1,2)$, $\exists n \in N^+$ let there is no $m \in N^+$ satisfy the inequality$$q^n-q^{n-1}+1 \le q^m\lt q^{n+1}-q^n+1$$

The inequality can be written as $$q^{n-1}\le\frac{q^m-1}{q-1}\lt q^n$$

The sum of the geometric sequence is bigger than the $n-1$th term and the $n$th

term of a geometric sequence with a common ratio of $q$.

But I don't know what I can do next.

I am not sure whether the statement is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider fixed arbitrary $q \in (1,2)$. Consider $q^i(2-q)$ as $i$ varies. This diverges to infinity, so in particular is eventually $\geq 1$. Also $q^0(2-q)=2-q<1$. Thus there exists a smallest integer $k$ with $q^k(2-q) \geq 1$, and we have $k \geq 1$. By minimality of $k$ we get $q^{k-1}(2-q)<1$.

Take $n=k \in \mathbb{N}^{+}$. We get 
$$q^{k-1}=q^{k-1}(q-1)+q^{k-1}(2-q)<q^{k-1}(q-1)+1=q^k-q^{k-1}+1$$
$$q^k=q^k(q-1)+q^k(2-q) \geq q^k(q-1)+1=q^{k+1}-q^k+1$$
We are thus done, as $q^k-q^{k-1}+1 \leq q^m<q^{k+1}-q^k+1$ then implies $k-1<m<k$, a contradiction, so no such $m$ exists.

Remark: In fact it is possible to show that $q(2-q)<1$ for $q\in (1,2)$, thus $k \geq 2$, which reconciles with the fact that $m=1$ always works when $n=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon_n \in [0,1] \forall n$ with $\epsilon_{t+1}>\epsilon_t$.

We have that $q$ is expressible as $1+\epsilon_1$. This leads to: $$1+\epsilon_2-\epsilon_3\leq q^m < 1+\epsilon_3 - \epsilon_2$$
This draws that the only possible integer solution is $0$, which isn't positive.

Comment: I do not understand why the unique integer solution is 0.

Comment: Two reasons. $$|\epsilon_3-\epsilon_2|<1$$ and $q^0=1$

Comment: I still cannot catch your point and your reason. Could you explain your method with more details?

Comment: I implied that $$(1+\epsilon_1)^n=1+\epsilon_2$$, and $$(1+\epsilon_1)^{n+1}=1+\epsilon_3$$ and then applied that to the original statement

Answer (score 0):

$q^n-q^{n-1}+1
\le q^m 
\lt q^{n+1}-q^n+1
$

The right inequality 
implies $m \le n$ because
$q^{n+1}-q^n+1
\lt q^{n+1}
$
so $m < n+1$
so $m \le n$.

The left inequality,
in contrast,
has many solutions.

Write it as
$q^{n-1}(q-1)+1
\le q^m 
$
and let
$q = 1+x$
where
$0 < x < 1$.
It becomes
$x(1+x)^{n-1}+1
\le (1+x)^m 
$.

If $\frac1{n} \le x \le \frac1{n-1}$,
then
$(1+x)^{n-1}
\le (1+\frac1{n-1})^{n-1}
\lt e
$
so the left side is less than
$1+\frac{e}{n-1}
$.

For the right side,
$q^m
=(1+x)^m
\ge 1+mx
\ge 1+\frac{m}{n}
$
so the left inequality is true if
$1+\frac{e}{n-1}
\lt 1+\frac{m}{n}
$
or
$m > \frac{en}{n-1}
\gt 5
$
if
$n \ge 2
$.

Therefore,
for any $m > 5$ and $n > 2$
we can find a $q$
so that the left inequality holds.

Comment: actually, the question I ask is to show for all q in the interval there is always existing n to let no positive integer m satisfy the inequality. I will edit again the question to let it less confusing.

Comment: I have already tried to close this question. The question posted on this web is clearer than this. If you still have the interest in the question I asked. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3064930/show-that-for-any-q-in-the-interval-1-2-exists-n-to-let-the-inequality-o